# ¿Como hacer un Query de tres tablas con llaves foraneas diferentes? SQL

Tags: base-de-datos, sql, select, join

Necesito un select con Join que me de como resultado una tabla que reuna:

Id_clien, nombre_clien, sum(precio_venta)

ejm resultado:
1520,    andres,    234234

Donde Id_clien y nombre_clien los toma de la tabla **cliente**,
sum(precio_venta) es la suma de todos los "precio_venta" relacionados con ese Id_cliente en **inventario**, el cual se asocia indirectamente por medio de la tabla **factura_venta**.

Estas son las tablas a utilizar:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cliente (
id_clien NUMBER(6), 
nombre_clien VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, 
apellido_clien VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, 
direccion_clien VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, 
telefono_clien NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL, 
correo_clien VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT cliente_idclien_pk PRIMARY KEY(id_clien));
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE factura_venta (
id_venta NUMBER(5),
fecha_venta DATE NOT NULL, 
id_clien NUMBER(6) NOT NULL, 
id_emp NUMBER(2) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT factura_venta_idventa_pk PRIMARY KEY(id_venta), 
CONSTRAINT factura_venta_idclien_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_clien) REFERENCES cliente (id_clien), 
CONSTRAINT factura_venta_idemp_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_emp) REFERENCES empleado (id_emp));
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE detalle_venta (
id_detallev NUMBER(5),
id_venta NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
id_inv NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT detalle_venta_idinv_uk UNIQUE (id_inv),
CONSTRAINT detalle_venta_iddetallev_pk PRIMARY KEY(id_detallev),
CONSTRAINT detalle_venta_idventa_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_venta) REFERENCES factura_venta (id_venta), 
CONSTRAINT detalle_venta_idinv_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_inv) REFERENCES inventario (id_inv));
```

```css
CREATE TABLE inventario (
id_inv NUMBER(5), 
precio_venta NUMBER(6) NOT NULL, 
precio_compra NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,
id_detallec NUMBER(5) NOT NULL, 
id_color NUMBER(2) NOT NULL, 
id_talla NUMBER(2) NOT NULL, 
id_est NUMBER(1) NOT NULL, 
id_prod NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT inventario_iddetallec_uk UNIQUE (id_detallec),
CONSTRAINT inventario_idinv_pk PRIMARY KEY(id_inv), 
CONSTRAINT inventario_iddetallec_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_detallec) REFERENCES detalle_compra (id_detallec), 
CONSTRAINT inventario_idcolor_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_color) REFERENCES color (id_color),
CONSTRAINT inventario_idtalla_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_talla) REFERENCES talla (id_talla), 
CONSTRAINT inventario_idest_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_est) REFERENCES estado (id_est), 
CONSTRAINT inventario_idprod_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_prod) REFERENCES producto (id_prod));
```

Adjunto MER 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender como funciona el sitio y a leer [ask]. Finalmente, suigero que edites e incluyas en tu pregunta lo que has intentado hasta ahora, que no funciona, pues en su estado actual la pregunta parece una solicitud de realizar tu tarea (o tu trabajo) y eso no es bien recibido por acá. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Y la consulta que has intentado? ¿Investigaste cómo se unen las tablas, los tipos de `JOIN` que hay, etc? ¿Cuál es la dificultad o el error?

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si la respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

La consulta que estás buscando es:

```
SELECT id_clien,SUM(precio_venta)
  FROM cliente JOIN factura_venta USING(id_clien)
  JOIN detalle_venta USING(id_venta)
  JOIN inventario USING(id_inv)
  GROUP BY 1;
```

Dado que eres nuevo colaborador, debes tener en cuenta lo que te han dicho en los comentarios:

- Debes intentar hacer algo tú mismo, es la mejor forma de aprender. Es cierto que mirando cómo lo hacemos los demás se aprende, pero mucho más despacio.
- Hubiera estado bien que nos pasaras los datos del ejemplo para confirmar que nos salen los mismos resultados que a ti:

> ejm resultado: 1520, andres, 234234

- En las etiquetas debes detallar el sistema gestor de bases de datos que utilizas, yo he supuesto MySQL pero, por los tipos de datos que usas, seguro que se trata de otro.
- Genial por aportar la estructura en SQL de las tabas, sólo que no nos las has dado en orden y, al tener definidas FK de tablas que no nos has pasado, ha habido que retocar el código para poder probarlo. Te adjunto cómo deberías habérnoslas pasado (si caben en el ancho de la pantalla, mejor):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE cliente (
>   id_clien int, 
>   nombre_clien VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
>   apellido_clien VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
>   direccion_clien VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
>   telefono_clien varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
>   correo_clien VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
>   CONSTRAINT cliente_idclien_pk PRIMARY KEY(id_clien)
>   );
>
> CREATE TABLE factura_venta (
>   id_venta int,
>   fecha_venta DATE NOT NULL, 
>   id_clien int NOT NULL, 
>   id_emp int NOT NULL, 
>   CONSTRAINT factura_venta_idventa_pk
>     PRIMARY KEY(id_venta), 
>   CONSTRAINT factura_venta_idclien_fk
>     FOREIGN KEY (id_clien) REFERENCES cliente (id_clien) 
>   );
>
> CREATE TABLE inventario (
>   id_inv int(5), 
>   precio_venta int(6) NOT NULL, 
>   precio_compra int(6) NOT NULL,
>   id_detallec int(5) NOT NULL, 
>   id_color int(2) NOT NULL, 
>   id_talla int(2) NOT NULL, 
>   id_est int(1) NOT NULL, 
>   id_prod int(5) NOT NULL,
>   CONSTRAINT inventario_iddetallec_uk
>     UNIQUE (id_detallec),
>   CONSTRAINT inventario_idinv_pk
>     PRIMARY KEY(id_inv));
>
> CREATE TABLE detalle_venta (
>   id_detallev int,
>   id_venta int NOT NULL,
>   id_inv int NOT NULL,
>   CONSTRAINT detalle_venta_idinv_uk UNIQUE (id_inv),
>   CONSTRAINT detalle_venta_iddetallev_pk
>     PRIMARY KEY(id_detallev),
>   CONSTRAINT detalle_venta_idventa_fk
>     FOREIGN KEY (id_venta) REFERENCES factura_venta (id_venta),
>     CONSTRAINT detalle_venta_idinv_fk
>     FOREIGN KEY (id_inv) REFERENCES inventario (id_inv)
>   );
> ```

Bienvenido y espero que nos envíes muchas más dudas.